# Fluid dynamic image layout with sorting issues

Tags: javascript, css

i am working on

```
http://www.hotchinesebabes.com/
```

**THE SITE IS SAFE FOR WORK, NO NUDE IMAGES**

And i wanted a fluid layout where the images could vary in height, but still be aligned, i also wanted filtering. (Catagory sorting client side).

Now i have run in to an issue.

I am using:

http://mixitup.io/ MixItUp for the filtering

and

http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/ blocksit for the layout

The issue is that blocksit creats the layout with position absolutte, and by doing that, mixitup cannot sort the catagories properly, if you click on the "Hot" catagory, it filters the images, but the buttom images do not float up, due to position absolutte.

Are there any plugins that combine these features, or any plugins that can be combined without cousing a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [**Masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) it seems to meet your requirements.